# SSAS Row Count Aggregation

Tags: sql, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Hi I have a table like this:

```
idCustomer  |    idTime      | idStatus
---------------------------------
    1       |   20010101     |    2
    1       |   20010102     |    2
    1       |   20010103     |    3
    2       |   20010101     |    1
...
```

I have now added this table as a factless fact table in my cube with a measure which aggregates the row count for each customer, so that for each day I can see how many customers are at each status and I can drill down to see which customers they are.

This is all well and good but when I roll it up to the month or year level it start summing up the values of each day where instead I want to see the last non empty value.

I'm not sure if this is possible but I can't think of another way of getting this information without creating a fact table with the counts for each status on each day and loosing the ability to drill down.

Can anyone help??

Comment: How exactly have you defined your "measure which aggregates the row count for each customer"? As count of rows? As distinct count of customer id? As count of non-empty customer ids?

Comment: As a count of rows. On my cube I created a new measure where the usage is "Count" and the source table is my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get what you want would be to convert your factless fact table to one having a fact: the count. Just add a named calculation to the table object in the data source view. Name the calculation like you want your measure to be named, and use `1` as the expression. Then you can define a measure based on this calculation using the aggregate function "LastNonEmpty", and use this instead of your current count measure.